# How to make beamer citations follow overlays?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, citing, overlays

I have a slide where I want to display two quotes with citations. I use `\onslide` to reveal one quote at a time with `\footcite` to display citations to the sources.

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[natbib=true, style=alphabetic, citestyle=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \onslide<1->{
    \begin{quote}
       Quote 1 \footcite{palen_success_2015}.
    \end{quote}
  }
  \vfill
  \onslide<2->{
    \begin{quote}
      Quote 2 \footcite{crawford_what_2016}.
    \end{quote}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I want the citations to be displayed only when the quotes are displayed. However, the citations in the footnote appear on every slide.

[image]
[image]

How can I reveal the citations only when the `footcite` is displayed?

**Edit** I disagree that this question should be marked duplicate. When I was searching for an answer to my question, I did not find the proposed duplicate. Also, I think many people may not understand how the answer to that question can be used to solve the problem.  Even though both questions deal with the relationship between citations and `only`, they seem different enough to both exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide the second citation on the first slide by using `\only<2->{}`

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor=dvipsnames, aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\usepackage[natbib=true, style=alphabetic, citestyle=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \onslide<1->{
    \begin{quote}
       Quote 1 \footcite{palen_success_2015}.
    \end{quote}
  }
  \vfill
  \onslide<2->{
    \begin{quote}
      Quote 2 \only<2>{\footcite{crawford_what_2016}}.
    \end{quote}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! I'm a bit puzzled about why `footcite` respects `only` but on `onslide`.  Can you explain?

Comment: @groceryheist The difference is that with `onslide` the content is merely hidden from the slide, while with `only` the content is not at all typeset on the slide.